# Anchor link linking to wrong place on page

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, anchor

I have a link to a div on my home page in my main navigation. However, the link is landing way further down the page. It seems to work ok in Firefox but not Chrome. Here is the link:

http://purplecubed.com/home#what-we-do

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I see a lot of errors in console.log, so I think you should take care of them at first and then check your //Navigation Scrolling in script.js, I'm pretty sure the problem is there.

Comment: Can confirm it works fine in Firefox.  Looks like you need to check your source links to your images and css files are correct as quite a few can't be found.

Answer (score 1):

This is just speculation, but here's what *appears* to be happening: When your page load includes very long-running HTTP requests (like some of your PNG images which return 404s but take upwards of 5 seconds to do so), Chrome goes ahead and renders the page without them, then navigates down to the appropriate div location. Once the requests complete but the images are not returned, the space that would have been taken by those images is collapsed and you get less pixels above the viewport, making it seem as though you landed further down the page on page-load.

However, FireFox appears to be rendering the entire page and waiting for all requests to return before attempting the navigation which causes the missing images to collapse prior to jumping down to the correct location in the page. Check your image locations and fix the URLs. This should fix the issue. If it doesn't, comment here again and I'll look for a better solution.

Comment: I solved it by wrapping the jquery smooth scrolling code i $(window).load(function(){}). This way it waits for all content to be loaded before executing